# Providing Search facility

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, search

I have a web page with following fields

```
name,address,post
```

with three textboxes.I want to provide the search facility to the user.if user enter only the name and hit search it should search only by name, if user enter the values for all the textboxes it should query the database with all 3 values.like wise how can i write the sql query for all the searching possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from Table1
where
  (coalesce(@Name, '') = '' or Name = @Name) and
  (coalesce(@Address, '') = '' or Address = @Address) and
  (coalesce(@Post, '') = '' or Post = @Post)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this option for the query. If the user enters a value in only one of the fields, then pass a null to the parameter of the other respective fields.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetPeople]
@name varchar(50),
@Address varchar(200),
@Post varchar(5)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select name, address, post 
from tblPeople 
where (name = @Name or @Name IS NULL) and
  (address = @Address or @Address IS NULL) and
  (post = @Post or @Post IS NULL)
```

A simple VB.NET example to call the stored procedure:

```
Dim strName As String = NameTextBox.Value
Dim strAddress as string = AddressTextBox.Value
Dim strPost as string = PostTextBox.Value
Dim strSQL As String = "uspGetPeople"
Dim strConn As String = "My.Database.ConnectionString"
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
If not string.isnullorempty(strName) then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName)
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dbnull.value)
End if
If not string.isnullorempty(strPost) then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", strPost)
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", dbnull.value)
End if
If not string.isnullorempty(strAddress) then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", strAddress)
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", dbnull.value)
End if

Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Using cn
   cn.Open()
   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
   While dr.Read
       'process records returned
       'dr("name")
       'dr("address")
       'dr("post")             
   End While
   cn.Close()
End Using
```